# SQL Server 2012 OUT OF MEMORY error messages

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to trying to run some insert code(about 40,000 of them) using SSMS but I keep running up against SQL out of memory errors among others. I would appreciate any help to fix this problem please.

[image: **Error message that shows up when I try to run my query**]

[image: **Another SQL Error message that showed up as well**]
[image: Database Property]

Comment: How much free disk space do you have on the DB server? How much RAM exists on the server? This is likely an issue with the DB server running out of disk space.

Comment: SilverNinja, I just uploaded data on my database. Is that the information you requested?

Comment: You need log space for the 40K inserts, try inserting 10K or 20K at a time to see if you can get around the memory limit. Your DB log is probably filling up.

Comment: That last stack trace seems to come from an addin rather than SSMS itself. [SQL Test](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-test/)

Comment: Yes, but I am having a hard time finding a way to uninstall them all so I can be sure they are not the cause of some of the issues I have been having. Can you please help me with that detail?

Comment: I'm not sure that it will fix the issue either. SSMS presumably consumes quite a lot of memory doing stuff like parsing for intellisense and colour coding. I'd probably just use the `sqlcmd` utility to run your script.

Comment: I have been using SSMS for years and this is the first time I have run up against this sort of issue.

Comment: Have you previously been able to run batches of SQL that size?

Comment: Yes,I have worked on bigger sets than this with no problems. This problem started only a couple of hours ago, and  I have no idea why or what caused it.

Comment: I think the problem is the use of Comic Sans.

Answer (score 3):

This exception is a .NET exception, so it cannot come from SQL Server. It comes from SSMS itself. *Your* machine has not enough ram.

OutOfMemoryException also has nothing to do with disk space. It refers to RAM.

Comment: I have 6GB of memory on this machine and I am able to run every thing application with no problem.

Comment: SSMS is a 32bit application. I guess your workload is exhausting virtual memory. Look into task manager to confirm (virtual size and private bytes).

Comment: Btw, executing huge SQL batches is known to exceed memory limits. This is normal and it is not what SSMS or SQL Server handle well. Usually, batchs are small (just a few statements, not 40k).

Comment: @Kobojunkie still the message is unambiguous. A different component produced it then. As a .NET dev I know what this message means. Also, SQL Server cannot be the problem because you didn't start to execute! The dialog box title is "SQL Test". Maybe you have a plugin?

Comment: Don't trust Task Manager at all. Use SysInternals tools and/or perfmon.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of digging, I decided to uninstall all of the Redgate tools that I had been using with my SQL installation. It seems that the problem was being caused by one of these tools.

Comment: I'd include this in your question. Also, did you uninstall the tools from your server or your machine?